# Can't get UI in Spring

Tags: spring, user-interface, spring-boot, null, vaadin

In the first Version of my program, I load MainScreen without problems on this way:

```
public class MyUI extends UI {

    public void showMainView() {
        addStyleName(ValoTheme.UI_WITH_MENU);
        setContent(new MainScreen(MyUI.this));
        mainScreen.setUI(MyUI.this);  
    }

    public static MyUI get() {
        return (MyUI) UI.getCurrent();
    }
}
```

But now, I have changed it to:

```
@SpringUI
@Viewport("user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0")
@Theme("mytheme")

public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Autowired
    MainScreen mainScreen;

    public void showMainView() {
        addStyleName(ValoTheme.UI_WITH_MENU);
        setContent(mainScreen);
        getNavigator().navigateTo(getNavigator().getState());  
    }

    public static MyUI get() {
        return (MyUI) UI.getCurrent();
    }

}
```

To get MainScreen via @Autowired, I had to clear the Constructor of MainScreen, but I **don't know how to get now the UI I need for navigator**.

I just get **null** in both ways.

```
@Component
@UIScope
public class MainScreen extends HorizontalLayout {

    public MainScreen() {

        UI ui = UI.getCurrent();     // is null
        MyUI ui2 = MyUI.get();       // is null

        CssLayout viewContainer = new CssLayout();
        viewContainer.addStyleName("valo-content");
        viewContainer.setSizeFull();

        final Navigator navigator = new Navigator(ui, viewContainer);

        // ... 

}
```

Comment: Usually the [navigator](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-navigator.html) is configured when init-ing the UI because they're pretty connected together and it's kind of the logical place to do it. You can also check the [Vaadin wiki for a quick spring-vaadin integration](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Spring+Vaadin/I+-+Getting+Started+with+Vaadin+Spring+and+Spring+Boot) (be sure to read all 5 sections, the 3rd one is related to navigation).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with all the frameworks you tagged. I'm going to address what I believe to be a logical error or possibly an incorrect design.

If you `@Autowire` the `MainScreen` into the `UI` you're allowing spring to guarantee whatever that is to be there. If you look at it using the preferred constructor injection it might be more obvious.

```
public class MyUI extends UI {

    private MainScreen mainScreen;

    @Autowired
    public MyUI (MainScreen mainScreen) {
        this.mainScreen = mainScreen;
    }
}
```

`MainScreen` has already been instantiated at that point and could very well be in other parts of the code already so the `mainScreen` constructor shouldn't be dependent on `MyUI`.

How you deal with it is depends on what the desired behavior and relationship is. If you're needing the `UI` class in `mainScreen` but can't depend on it being available then you'll have to pass it in from the `UI` class itself (`mainScreen.foo(this);`).